# Pulling user/group field data from SharePoint list using REST, jQuery, Knockout.js Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, rest, ajax

I'm trying to make an interactive task board based on the task list app in SharePoint 2013. The task lisk includes fields like "Title","Description","Status","% Complete","Due Date","Assigned To", etc. I used knockout.js to bind "Title","Description", and  "Status" to my HTML controls. Here is some of the code:

```
var ViewModal = function(items, listname){
var self = this;

self.sortBy = ko.observableArray(sortBy);
self.tasks = ko.observableArray(items);
self.listname = ko.observable(listname);
self.auto = ko.observable(false);

self.getTasks = function() {

    clearTimeout(self.getTasks);

    // server relative url to REST service endpoint
    var ajaxurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + self.listname() + "?$orderby=PriorityValue";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ajaxurl,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        processData: true,
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {

            if (status == "success" && data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data.d.results, mapping, self.tasks)

                $(".task-item").draggable();
            }
        },
        error: alert
    });

    if (self.auto()) {
        setTimeout(self.getTasks, 10000);
    }
};

<div class="tasks-column">
<div class="column-header">Not Started</div>

<!-- ko foreach: tasksNotStarted -->

<div class="task-item">
    <div class="view" data-bind="visible: !IsEditing()">
        <button class="edit" data-bind="click: $root.editTask">edit</button>
        <h2><span data-bind="text: Title"></span></h2>
        <div data-bind="html: Description"></div>
        <span data-bind="text: PriorityValue"></span>
    </div>
    <div clsas="edit" data-bind="visible: IsEditing">
        <button class="save" data-bind="click: $root.saveTask">save</button>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Title"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm having trouble displaying the data from the "Assigned To" user/group field. I tried:

```
<span data-bind="text: AssignedTo"></span>
```

But it displays the field as [object Object]

I tried using $expand

```
var ajaxurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + self.listname() = "?$expand=AssignedTo";
```

But I still get [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the syntax Amal suggested but in the select statement, then expand the entire AssignedTo object.

When you're on a page with jQuery loaded open your browser dev tools and enter this into the JavaScript console:

```
$.getJSON(
    "/_api/lists/getByTitle('Tasks')/items?$select=AssignedTo/Id,AssignedTo/Title&$expand=AssignedTo",
     function(data) { console.log(data) }
)
```

Note I've used the `/_api/` path to make the request, you really should use this endpoint instead of calling in to `listdata.svc` for all new development against 2013.

The snippet above will log the response object into the Javascript console where you can inspect it. If you expand the response object a couple of levels you'll see that `AssignedTo` is actually an array of more objects with your `Title` and `Id` properties. So if you were going to bind this in your knockout context you would need to use something like:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: AssignedTo">
    <span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
</div>
```

Or you can do something more slick like

```
<span data-bind="text: [].map.call(AssignedTo, function(item) { return item.Title })"></span>
```

Which will give you a comma separated list, you can add a leading space if you want in the return block too.

If you're super set on using `listdata.svc` then you would use the same syntax:

```
"/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Tasks?$select=AssignedTo/Id,AssignedTo/Title&$expand=AssignedTo"
```

But the trick here is that when you use listdata.svc like this, your `AssignedTo` objects will each have their own `results` object that holds the array of values. So you would need to bind to `AssignedTo.value[i].Title`

Either way I think this should give you enough to get started -- don't hesitate to crack open your browser tools or use something like [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) to inspect the results of your REST calls directly so you can navigate the object hierarchies and get what you're looking for -- you'll learn more as you go this way too!

Comment: I changed the url to the /_api/ endpoint but I got an error from Postman that basically said AssignedTo doesn't exist. I used listdata.svc and took out the $select and just did $expand=AssignedTo. I set the bind to AssignedTo.Title like Amal mentioned but it returned the user's job title. I used Postman to and found 'Name' and set the bind to AssignedTo.Name and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. You could either examine the person object returned in the browser developer toolbar and extract what you need from it but I'd recommend using ["Knockout bindings for SharePoint"](http://kosp.codeplex.com/), a great codeplex project for dealing with some of the more complex objects that SharePoint returns.

Once you have added a reference to it (and other dependent JavaScript libraries) your binding would look like this:

```
<span data-bind="spUser: AssignedTo"></span>
```

or if you have AssignedTo set to accept multiple selections:

```
<span data-bind="spUser: AssignedTo, multi:true"></span>
```

If it is not returning anything, try changing the binding to `<span data-bind="spUser:CreatedBy"></span>` as this will verify that KOSP is working.

This will render it as a nice clickable link. Have a look at some of the [project author's blogs](http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Introducing-KoSp-Knockout-binding-handlers-for-SharePoint-2013-and-2010-Rest-API-and-SPServices.aspx) on the subject to get you up and running.

Comment: I tried using that library but it either doesn't return anything or it returns a blank/null value.

Comment: Just added a line in case you returning multi select and a good way of testing KOSP is installed

Comment: I tried CreatedBy but it didn't work. I'm using ko.sp-1.0.min.Ex.js. I tried it with knockout-2.3.0.js and knockout-3.0.0beta.js but it's still not returning anything.